# How do I use TikZ graphdrawing package with KTikZ+LuaLaTeX?

Tags: ktikz

How do I use TikZ graphdrawing package with KTikZ+LuaLaTeX?

Putting the following code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs} 

 \tikz [rounded corners]
\graph [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
{
 a -> {
b,
 c -> { d, e }
} ->
f ->
a
};
```

gives this error:

> [LaTeX] Line 5: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key
>   '/tikz/graphs/layered layout' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
>   misspelled it.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot "la"; use 'lualatex'

Comment: @morbusg Aaah! You are right! ☺

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need the `graphdrawing` library, and `\usegdlibrary{layered}`.

Make a new template; call it, say, "lualatex-graphdrawing-template.pgs":

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs} 
\usegdlibrary{layered}


\begin{document}
<>
\end{document}
```

Then, in KTikZ, putting, with the above template selected, this code:

```
 \tikz [rounded corners]
\graph [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
{
 a -> {
b,
 c -> { d, e }
} ->
f ->
a
};
```

will render:

[image]

Also, remember that you need to set KTikZ to use `lualatex` for rendering, not `pdflatex`.

Comment: I think for KTikZ you need to fiddle with the options to change the compile engine.

Comment: @percusse Nope, Settings --> Configure KTikZ.

Comment: OK replace **options** with settings :)